# USB to UART Bridge IC question

Tags: usb, uart, digital-communications, bridge

I have a few basic questions regarding this [USB to UART bridge IC](https://www.maxlinear.com/ds/xr21b1424.pdf)

My questions are just from the hardware perspective. I have little to no software knowledge. So please bear with me and help me understand your answer in simple terms.

1. This IC converts USB protocol to UART protocol at the available 4 output channels, right? Is there any software within the IC that will do this conversion of protocol or do we have to write separately? Like, what should a hardware person keep in mind while using the IC? Like, just connect differential lines on Input and take 4 Tx,Rx lines on the output connected appropriately to the Micro or SOC or whatever IC?
2. If I have one USB 2.0 running at 480Mb/s connected as the input, how is speed and addressing done for each channel? Will all output UART channels operate at the same speed? What happens if two output channels require value from USB at the same time?

Comment: I have no experience with this particular IC. In general, these types of USB/UART bridges require a special software driver on the computer connected to the USB side. Once this driver is loaded, the system should behave as if your peripherals were connected to the UART directly in your computer. No need to write special code to run on the IC.

Comment: On the hardware side just connect as if you would connect to an UART interface on one side and as an USB interface on the other. UART baud rate control should be taken care by the software driver - take a look at their documentation. The IC should be smart enough to use buffering and serialization to deal with simultaneous UART communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Usually when you have a multichannel USB to UART bridge it simply appears in the system as multiple serial ports, so you don't need anything special to communicate over one of the UARTs. In Windows for example you will simply have 4 COM ports.
2. The datasheet says that an individual UART can go up to 12 Mbps. Each channel speed can be set separately (just like in every other serial port). USB does not have very predictable timings, but you can count on the chip (and you operating system) to reliably deliver all the data. That is what the FIFOs in the chip are for - to hold the data until it can be transmitted.

Comment: In addition standart CDC drivers, the IC maybe needs MaxLinear driver to access internal registers in specific circumstances. The IC differs standart FT232 similar ICs with plenty of registers that can be accessible(or should be) by user. Some settings e.g. GPIO, FIFO count, flow control can be done via registers inside the IC. You may need to use special driver software for this.